# How to display the first and the last value

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a problem with my query -  I only want to display the first and last idle of each iteration. For example, in this case, the tagids 4886 and 4889 will appear and the active and stop statuses are correct. only idle should display the start and end, it is not necessary for all idle states to appear.

[This is the query result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JevU0.png)

```
   WITH LaggedHyd101 AS (
        SELECT
            [tagid],
            [recordtime],
            [D1],
            [D2],
            [D3],
            [D4],
            [D5],
            [D6],
            [D7],
            [D8],
            [D9],
            [D10],
            [D11],
            [D12],
            [D13],
            [D14],
            [D15],
            [D16],
            [D17],
            [D18],
            LEAD([D17]) OVER (ORDER BY [recordtime] DESC) AS LaggedD17,
            LEAD([D18]) OVER (ORDER BY [recordtime] DESC) AS LaggedD18
        FROM
            [INFOU_CCR23].[dbo].[HYD101]
    )
    SELECT
        [tagid],
        [recordtime] AS StartTime,
        LAG([recordtime]) OVER (ORDER BY [recordtime] DESC) AS StopTime,
        [D1],
        [D2],
        [D3],
        [D4],
        [D5],
        [D6],
        [D7],
        [D8],
        [D9],
        [D10],
        [D11],
        [D12],
        [D13],
        [D14],
        [D15],
        [D16],
        [D17],
        [D18],
        ABS(DATEDIFF(MINUTE, LAG([recordtime]) OVER (ORDER BY [recordtime] DESC), [recordtime])) AS DifferentTime,
        CASE
            WHEN ([D18] = 0 AND [D17] = 0) THEN 'Stop'
            WHEN ([D18] = 1 AND [D17] > 0 ) THEN 'Active'
            WHEN ([D18] = 1 AND  LaggedD17 = 0) THEN 'Idle'
            ELSE NULL
        END AS Status
    FROM
        LaggedHyd101
    WHERE
        ([D18] = 0 AND (LaggedD18 IS NULL OR LaggedD18 = 1))
        OR
        ([D18] = 1 AND (LaggedD18 IS NULL OR LaggedD18 = 0))
        OR
        ([D18] = 1  AND (LaggedD18 IS NULL OR LaggedD17 = 0 ))
    ORDER BY
        [recordtime] DESC;
```

I am expecting correct query from logic

```
tagid   StartTime   StopTime    D1  D2  D3  D4  D5  D6  D7  D8  D9  D10 D11 D12 D13 D14 D15 D16 D17 D18 DifferentTime   Status
5851    2024-01-09 14:56:08.063 NULL    HYD-101     375 137 50  69  1500                                                        1500    900 4054                            650 1   NULL    Active
5850    2024-01-09 14:55:10.470 2024-01-09 14:56:08.063 HYD-101     381 47  50  11  1501                                                        1500    0   4054                            0   1   1   Idle
5565    2024-01-09 10:10:10.467 2024-01-09 14:55:10.470 HYD-101     387 0   0   0   0                                                       1500    0   4054                            0   0   285 Stop
5475    2024-01-09 08:40:10.470 2024-01-09 10:10:10.467 HYD-101     376 123 50  62  1500                                                        1500    900 4053                            650 1   90  Active
5105    2024-01-09 02:30:10.467 2024-01-09 08:40:10.470 HYD-101     383 0   0   0   0                                                       1500    0   4053                            0   0   370 Stop
5019    2024-01-09 01:04:08.063 2024-01-09 02:30:10.467 HYD-101     382 45  50  9   1501                                                        1500    0   4051                            400 1   86  Active
5018    2024-01-09 01:03:08.060 2024-01-09 01:04:08.063 HYD-101     381 45  50  9   1501                                                        1500    0   4051                            0   1   1   Idle
5002    2024-01-09 00:47:08.067 2024-01-09 01:03:08.060 HYD-101     384 0   0   0   0                                                       1500    0   4051                            0   0   16  Stop
4890    2024-01-08 22:55:10.470 2024-01-09 00:47:08.067 HYD-101     374 124 50  62  1501                                                        1500    900 4049                            680 1   112 Active
4889    2024-01-08 22:54:08.063 2024-01-08 22:55:10.470 HYD-101     377 44  50  9   1500                                                        1500    0   4049                            0   1   1   Idle
4888    2024-01-08 22:53:08.063 2024-01-08 22:54:08.063 HYD-101     378 44  50  9   1500                                                        1500    0   4049                            0   1   1   Idle
4887    2024-01-08 22:52:08.070 2024-01-08 22:53:08.063 HYD-101     377 44  50  9   1501                                                        1500    0   4049                            0   1   1   Idle
4886    2024-01-08 22:51:08.063 2024-01-08 22:52:08.070 HYD-101     378 44  50  9   1501                                                        1500    0   4049                            0   1   1   Idle
4801    2024-01-08 21:26:08.063 2024-01-08 22:51:08.063 HYD-101     375 121 50  60  1501                                                        1500    900 4048                            680 1   85  Active
4678    2024-01-08 19:23:08.060 2024-01-08 21:26:08.063 HYD-101     425 45  7   -1  304                                                     1500    0   4048                            0   0   123 Stop
4677    2024-01-08 19:22:08.063 2024-01-08 19:23:08.060 HYD-101     380 52  50  17  1500                                                        1500    0   4048                            0   1   1   Idle
4608    2024-01-08 18:13:08.063 2024-01-08 19:22:08.063 HYD-101     383 0   0   0   0                                                       1500    0   4048                            0   0   69  Stop
4486    2024-01-08 16:11:08.063 2024-01-08 18:13:08.063 HYD-101     372 123 50  61  1500                                                        1500    900 4046                            670 1   122 Active
```

Comment: A [mcve] is a great start when asking for SQL assistance. Note that most people here want both sample data and expected result as properly formatted text (no images, no links.)

Comment: With emphasis on minimal, we don't want your massive production query, rather a cut down example which demonstrates the problem.

Comment: Also please provide a title that actually represents the problem

Answer (score 0):

```
    WITH LaggedHyd101 AS (
--Existing
    ),
    NumberedRecords AS (
        SELECT *,
               ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [tagid] ORDER BY [StartTime]) AS FirstIdleRow,
               ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [tagid] ORDER BY [StartTime] DESC) AS LastIdleRow
        FROM LaggedHyd101
        WHERE Status = 'Idle'
    )
    SELECT *
    FROM NumberedRecords
    WHERE FirstIdleRow = 1 OR LastIdleRow = 1
    ORDER BY [tagid], [StartTime];
```

When something was idle in each group of your data, we number each item in a group and then just choose the first and last ones from these numbers.